# Me inicia sesión en dos proyectos al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, login, class

Hola compañeros del código,
me está surgiendo un problema que nunca me había ocurrido. Tengo un proyecto en un directorio en mi servidor: www.xxxxxxx.net/proyecto1

Este proyecto lo tengo desarrollado y lo he duplicado en el directorio 2 para usarlo como base para otro proyecto, así que tengo también www.xxxxxxx.net/proyecto2

Dupliqué también la base de datos y le hice una nueva para el proyecto2 de modo que trabajen de forma independiente. Hasta aquí todo bien, trabajan de forma independiente.

El problema reside cuando hago login o logout en cualquiera de los 2 proyecto. Si hago login en el proyecto1 y recargo la página del proyecto2 me hace login... y lo mismo si cierro sesión.

He estado comprobando el código y cada login comprueba en su base de datos independiente para hacer el login. Así que no se dónde puede estar el problema. 
Os pongo la parte del código del login.php que llama a la clase Login.

El código funciona correctamente, pero no sé porque me influye en los dos proyectos. ¿Podrá ser porque comparten servidor? Muchas gracias!

**login.php**

```
// load the login class
require_once("classes/Login.php");
// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process. in consequence, you can simply ...
$login = new Login();
// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
// the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
header("location: home.php");
} else {
// the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
?>
```

**classes/Login.php**

```
<?php /**
 * Class login
* handles the user's login and logout process
*/
class Login
{
/**
 * @var object The database connection
 */
private $db_connection = null;
/**
 * @var array Collection of error messages
 */
public $errors = array();
/**
 * @var array Collection of success / neutral messages
 */
public $messages = array();

/**
 * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
 * you know, when you do "$login = new Login();"
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // create/read session, absolutely necessary
    session_start();

    // check the possible login actions:
    // if user tried to log out (happen when user clicks logout button)
    if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
        $this->doLogout();
    }
    // login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
    elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $this->dologinWithPostData();
    }
}

/**
 * log in with post data
 */
private function dologinWithPostData()
{
    // check login form contents
    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {

        // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php (which we loaded in index.php)
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        // change character set to utf8 and check it
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

            // escape the POST stuff
            $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
            // username field)
            $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
                    FROM users
                    WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if this user exists
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                // get result row (as an object)
                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

                // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                // the hash of that user's password
                if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                    // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Problema de conexión de base de datos.";
        }
    }
}

/**
 * perform the logout
 */
public function doLogout()
{
    // delete the session of the user
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    // return a little feeedback message
    $this->messages[] = "Has sido desconectado.";

}

/**
 * simply return the current state of the user's login
 * @return boolean user's login status
 */
public function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    // default return
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $_SESSION Esta es una 'superglobal' o una variable automatic global. [Manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

lo que tienes que hacer es llamar la session del otro proyecto por otro vaiable,

Proyeto1:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
$_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
```

Proyecto2

```
// cambiar los valores de la session 
//en caso contrario siempre te devolvera los valores de la session proyecto1
$_SESSION['proyecto2_user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
$_SESSION['proyecto2_user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
$_SESSION['proyecto2_user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
$_SESSION['proyecto2_user_login_status'] = 1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! he cambiado las variables y ahora me inicia sesión por separado correctamente. El problema está en cerrar la sesión. Si la cierro en uno sigue cerrándola en el otro...
Creo que es por esta función, pero no se especificar que cierre solo el proyecto2 
    public function doLogout()
    {
        // delete the session of the user
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        // return a little feeedback message
        $this->messages[] = "Has sido desconectado.";

    }

Comment: Hay que cerrar la session iniciada en vez del global, primero comprueba la session iniciada y destruirla `unsert($_SESSION['proyecto1'])`.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero... no sé como cerrarla.
`unset($SESSION['que pongo aquí']);`
Digo esto porque la sesión que compruebo en cada página es esta:
`session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['naos_user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['naos_user_login_status'] != 1) {
        header("location: login.php");
  exit;
        }`
Al proyecto2 le he llamado **naos**

Comment: Para iniciar una session, dale un nombre a cada session proyecto1, proyecto2 *Nota: antes de iniciar una session hay que cerrar la otra* ya que las session se guardan en los navigadores y no en el servidor, en este caso en cada proyector nombre una session la cual hay que destruirla al cerrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo he solucionado. Un saludo!